# How Threaded class of pthreads treats object as an array

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

Recently i started studying multithreading in php. I am curious how Threaded class use object as an array in below code

```
<?php
$safe = new Threaded();

while (count($safe) < 10) {
    $safe[] = count($safe);
}

var_dump($safe->chunk(5));
```

If i apply the same logic in a normal class it gives a fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type XYZ as array
```

Comment: Is that your actual error or is XYZ replaced with something else?

Comment: Well i was experimenting by making a normal class and using it as an array and got the error

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface that allows your custom classes to work with `foreach` loops, etc.

You need to implement all five listed interface methods

- current
- key
- next
- rewind
- valid

What exactly you do inside each of these methods is entirely up to you - generally they're used to expose an array that is otherwise private to the object, or to provide some additional filtering/etc. There are plenty of examples in the documentation.

Any such object can have its iterable contents copied into a native array using the [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function.

In the case of the [`Threaded`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.threaded.php) class from pthreads, it's an internal PHP class, which implements the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface directly. This isn't possible in user-land.